# Processing giving me white window because height

Tags: java, processing

In processing, I need to fill a screen with rectangles based on its height. However, the code below is giving me a white screen. Anyone know why?

```
void setup (){
    size (600,600);
    background (255);
    fill (200,200,200);
    noStroke();
}

int y = 10;
int spatie = 20;
int stop = height;

void draw(){
    while(y < stop) { 
        rect (50,y,100,10);
        y = y + spatie;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your drawing loop is correct

```
void draw(){
    while(y < stop) { 
        rect (50,y,100,10);
        y = y + spatie;
    } 
}
```

but you cannot see rectangles because of other mistake.

When `Processing` object is intantiated all its fields (like `y`, `spatie`, `stop` in your case) are initialized. At this time variable `height` is set to `0` as screen height is unknown.

Next `setup()` is called and from this time `height` has value. But `stop` has value assigned at initialization phase. Next `draw()` is called in animation thread, but `stop` variable is frozen to value `0`.

Consider these small examples:

```
int stop = height;

public void setup() {
    size(800,600);
}

public void draw() {
    println("stop = " + stop);
}
```

and:

```
int stop;

public void setup() {
    size(800,600);
    stop = height;
}

public void draw() {
    println("stop = " + stop);
}
```

First will output: `stop = 0`

Second will print: `stop = 600`

Answer (score 0):

[Just ran your code](http://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/177507) and it is showing me 5 grey rectangles:

[image: OP's code]

So to achive rectangles unti the end of the screen, maybe use

```
for (int y = 0; y < height / spatie; y++) {
    rect (50, y * spatie, 100, 10);
}
```

Comment: Well, that's something. But it should go all the way till the end of the 'screen'.

Answer (score 0):

Just set up you're sketch and only removed `int stop = height;` and changed your while loop a bit (use `height` and use height instead of `stop`)

If you run the following code, it should work:

```
void setup(){
  size (600,800);
  background (255);
  fill (200,200,200);
  noStroke();
  noLoop();
}

int y = 10;
int spatie = 20;

void draw(){
  while(y<height){
    println(y);
    rect(50,y,100,10);
    y = y + spatie;
  }
}
```